# What is the best practice for login attempts and locking account accounts in asp.net membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

While I was testing my application, I realized that after 5 login attempts, the out of the box membership provider will lock your account.  How does a user go about getting his account unlocked?  Is the standard process just emailing the admin?  Or is there some form that i can build? email confirmation link?  Basically, the best practice for handling multiple failed login attempts.  I have increased the number to 10, and also I do not have a secret question and answer installed and would hope to avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

For strict security - I would suggest lockout with email to admin after minimum affordable attempts.

For less strict security requirements - in-memory lockout. For a half an hour for example. If user is being locked out in memory twice - do hard lockout(some membership provider customization needed).

Also another option - provide option for reset with secret question after lockout. After user notification successful being sent to him, remove lockout.